# SQLite database not displaying on button click

Tags: java, database, eclipse, sqlite, jtable

Evening all,

So I've been working on creating a local database using SQLite. (As a plugin that is part of Firefox). It uses three classes:

```
databaseConnection
Login
Display
```

and two tables (which come under the database `MyFilms`) called:

```
Users
MyFilms
```

`databaseConnection` is used to simply just connect to my SQLite database `MyFilms`, which it does fine.

The second class, Login, access my `Users` table from my database so it can access the logins and proceed to my GUI called `Display`.

`Display` will load the following GUI, which consists of a button, which when clicked is supposed to load the data from my database table `MyFilms` into a JTable:

[image]

However, when I click the button, nothing loads... it even looks like the JTable is not there, but when I check my code it defiantly is!

The code where I think the problem might lie is:

```
JButton btnLoadData = new JButton("Load Data");
btnLoadData.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        try{
            String query ="Select * from MyFilms";
            PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
            table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
        }
        catch (Exception anException){
            anException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Any idea why the database is not showing here? Please find the code to each class below:

**databaseConnection:**

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class databaseConnection {

    Connection conn = null; 

    public static Connection dbConnector(){
        try{
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\Joe\\workspace\\MyFilms.sqlite");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connection Successful!");
            return conn;
        }
        catch(Exception anException)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, anException);
            return null;
        }

        }
}
```

**Login:**

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Login {

    private JFrame frmTest;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Login window = new Login();
                    window.frmTest.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    Connection connection = null;
    private JTextField textFieldUN;
    private JPasswordField passwordField;

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Login() {
        initialize();
        connection = databaseConnection.dbConnector();
    }

    /**
     * Initialise the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frmTest = new JFrame();
        frmTest.setTitle("Database Login");
        frmTest.setBounds(100, 100, 345, 184);
        frmTest.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frmTest.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Username:");
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(34, 37, 64, 14);
        frmTest.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("Password:");
        lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(34, 66, 64, 14);
        frmTest.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_1);

        textFieldUN = new JTextField();
        textFieldUN.setBounds(126, 34, 151, 20);
        frmTest.getContentPane().add(textFieldUN);
        textFieldUN.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnLogin = new JButton("Login");
        frmTest.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(btnLogin);
        btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                try{
                    String query = "Select * from Users where username=? and password=?";
                    PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                    pst.setString(1, textFieldUN.getText());
                    pst.setString(2, passwordField.getText());

                    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
                    int count = 0;
                    while(rs.next()){
                        count = count +1;
                    }
                    if (count == 1){
                        frmTest.dispose();
                        Display GUI = new Display();
                        GUI.setVisible(true);
                    }

                    else if (count > 1){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Duplicate Username and Password");
                    }
                    else{
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username or Password is not correct - Please try again..");
                    }
                    rs.close();
                    pst.close();
                }       
                catch (Exception anException){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, anException);
                }

            }

        });
        btnLogin.setBounds(126, 111, 89, 23);
        frmTest.getContentPane().add(btnLogin);

        passwordField = new JPasswordField();
        passwordField.setBounds(126, 64, 151, 17);
        frmTest.getContentPane().add(passwordField);
    }
}
```

**Display:**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.sql.*;

public class Display extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTable table;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Display frame = new Display();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    Connection connection = null;
    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Display() {
        connection = databaseConnection.dbConnector();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 711, 443);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JButton btnLoadData = new JButton("Load Data");
        btnLoadData.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                try{
                    String query ="Select * from MyFilms";
                    PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
                    table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
                }
                catch (Exception anException){
                    anException.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        btnLoadData.setBounds(596, 11, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnLoadData);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(684, 45, -675, 349);
        contentPane.add(scrollPane);

        table = new JTable();
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Cheers..

However, when I run it in Eclipse I receive no errors at all. It runs fine, just does not display the database in the JTable.

Comment: You might get better help running this first through a debugger to see what is in fact happening as it runs.

Comment: Thanks @HovercraftFullOfEels, I've ran Display through a debugger and I've added the compilation info into the question.

Comment: Hi @HovercraftFullOfEels, I was wondering if you where able to help at all with this question? I've had no response from people and still unable to get it to work :(

Comment: I think you misunderstand me. Use Eclipse's debugger to find out what is wrong with your program's behavior as it runs. Without this, I don't think that anyone can help you.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks for your response, I've now run it through the Eclipse debugger, It says it suspends on line 29 of Display, which is the following line of code `EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {`

Comment: Put in break points and follow the results of the key variables. See if your database code is working, see if your GUI code is working. In essence follow the variable states to isolate your problem first and foremost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please replace your Display.java with the following:

Display.java

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils;

public class Display extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTable table;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Display frame = new Display();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    Connection connection = null;

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Display() {
        connection = databaseConnection.dbConnector();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 711, 443);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JButton btnLoadData = new JButton("Load Data");
        btnLoadData.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                try {
                    String query = "Select * from MyFilms";
                    PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
                    table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
                } catch (Exception anException) {
                    anException.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        // btnLoadData.setBounds(596, 11, 89, 23);
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        buttonPanel.add(btnLoadData, BorderLayout.EAST);

        contentPane.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        // scrollPane.setBounds(684, 45, -675, 349);

        table = new JTable();
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
        contentPane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}
```

and see the results?

Few changes have been made to your code. They are:

1) You first added `scrollPane` to the `contentPane` then you added `table` to `scrollPane`. I changed the order.

2) You used absolute layout. I changed that with `BorderLayout`.

The result displayed on my system is:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! Really appreciate your help. That has fixed the problem !